SF novel where the story, or part of it, is narrated by two linked brains taking turns
In which the story, or part of it, is narrated by two linked brains In which the story, or part of it, is narrated by two linked brains, maybe brother and sister, taking turns, while the other shuts down. I believe the female is maybe called Becky. I think the enemy who processed them are called the Bewegal, or similar. I believe I read this back in the 80's or 90's, so it is not a modern tale.

"We Fused Ones", a novelette by Perry A. Chapdelaine; first published in If, July 1968, available at the Internet Archive; reprinted in the anthology Mind at Bay (Christopher Evans, ed.), also available at the Internet Archive.
The brother and sister are named Becky and Johnny:

On the last day in my human form it seemed the most thrilling experience given to a lucky girl of only seventeen. I, Becky Ellents, had been chosen, along with my brother Johnny, to kick off opening ceremonies for the first deep-space Academy of Mines.

The aliens are indeed called the Bewegal:

The Bewegal, who made us the way we are now, had great need for micro-organic computers with redundant capacity; thus, Johnny and I share our experiences. Should one of us fail, the other can take immediate control, continuing in our efforts as though no failure had occurred. Otherwise, to insure that our operating-life will continue to be approximately equal throughout our design-life, our individual periods of conscious operation are controlled by an atomic timer.
I will tell our story for exactly two minutes and fifteen seconds; then Johnny, who will have been unconscious, yet completely conjoined to my experiences, will automatically take up our story for his allotted two minutes and fifteen seconds.
I will return at the end of his time to be followed by cycle after cycle of alternate self-awareness and control periods.


Brilliant. Many thanks for your prompt and accurate reply.
